# Split lines in text file separated by * into various lists Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Got a text file on the form:

```
* A
line
line
line
* B
line
* C
line
line
```

The amount of lines between each * is random.

I read the text file into a linkedlist with a while loop, but
I'm unsure how to put lines inbetween A and B into list for A, and
lines inbetween B and C into list for B and so forth.

Things I've tried

```
Linkedlist<String> lines = new Linkedlist<String>();
Linkedlist<String> linesA = new Linkedlist<String>();

while(file.hasNext()){
    lines.add(file.nextLine());  
}

for(String s : lines){
    if(s.contains("*") && s.contains("A")) {
        continue; //dont want this line into the list for A
    } else {
        linesA.add(s); 
        // this works for first part, but what should I do when I reach
        // the next *
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would drop the naming convention `linesA`, `linesB`, etc. and use an expanding `List<List<String>>` list to store the result you could do following:

```
List<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> current = null;
for (String s : lines) {
  if (s.startsWith("*")) {
    current = new LinkedList<>();
    result.add(current);
  } else {
    current.add(s);
  }
}
```

Above assumes a well formatted input. It's equivalent to:

```
List<String> linesA = result.get(0);
List<String> linesB = result.get(1);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map of lists, where the key is the letter of the group (such as `A`, `B`, etc.) and the value is the list of lines that correspond to the group. For example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> groups = new HashMap<>();
List<String> currentList = null;

for (String s: lines) {

    if(s.startsWith("*")) {
        String groupName = s.substring(2);
        currentList = new LinkedList<>();
        groups.put(groupName, currentList);
    } 
    else if (currentList != null) {
        currentList.add(s);
    }
}
```

If `groups` is printed, the result is:

```
{A=[line, line, line], B=[line], C=[line, line]}
```

`s.substring(2)` simply strips out the `*` from the head of the group name so that `* A` is reduced to `A`. To obtain list A, simply do a `get` on the `groups` map:

```
groups.get("A")
```